# How to remove namespace from Jaxb2 generated xml

Tags: java, spring, jaxb

I have a problem a little problem related to the namespaces in the XML marshalled by Jaxb2 . When I print out the xml file, I get this "extra" annotations on the xml tags. Is there any way to get rid of the extra namespace annotations ?

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes">
<root xmlns:ns2="http://www.something.com/something">
<ns2:food>steak</ns2:food>
<ns2:beverage>water</ns2:beverage>
</root>
```

I want to get rid of the ns2: namespace.

I tried with :

```
 <bean id="glsJaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPath" value="${gls.jaxb2.contextpath}"/>
    <property name="marshallerProperties">
        <map>

            <entry key="com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper">
                <bean class="es.fs.fswarehousing.gls.ws.EmptyNamespacePrefixMapper"/>
            </entry> 
   </map>
    </property>

</bean>
```

But im getting :

```
 ERROR [TaskExecutor-master-555-ProcessTask [8796749431734]] 
[ActionNode] Error executing
 org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB 
exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: 
com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper value: 
es.fs.fswarehousing.gls.ws.EmptyNamespacePrefixMapper@17f6a8fe
```

Can someone give me any hint :) ?

Comment: Why is `food` and `beverage` from a different namespace than `root`?

Comment: @Andreas That was just an example :) .